# Google Big Query accesses dataset in one way but not the other

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to query a google big query dataset.

When I run the following code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bqClient = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("/..../....json")

query ="""
SELECT
CONCAT(
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
view_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
ORDER BY view_count DESC
LIMIT 10
"""
#dry_run so no resources are wasted
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(dry_run=True)
query_job = bqClient.query(query, job_config = job_config)
iterator = query_job.result(timeout=30)
```

Error:

```
File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
iterator = query_job.result(timeout=30)
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 3129, in result
self.job_id, retry, project=self.project, location=self.location
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1112, in _get_query_results
retry, method="GET", path=path, query_params=extra_params
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 487, in _call_api
return call()
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
on_error=on_error,
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
return target()
File ".../python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 421, in api_request
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectone/queries/None?maxResults=0&location=US: Not found: Job projectone:US.None

(job ID: None)

           -----Query Job SQL Follows-----                

|    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |
1:
2:SELECT
3:  CONCAT(
4:    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
5:    CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
6:  view_count
7:FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
8:WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
9:ORDER BY view_count DESC
10:LIMIT 10
```

What is peculiar though is when I run:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("/.../...json")
stf_dataset_ref = client.dataset('stackoverflow', project='bigquery-public-data')
stf_dset = client.get_dataset(stf_dataset_ref)
print([x.table_id for x in client.list_tables(stf_dset)])
```

It returns:

['badges', 'comments', 'post_history', 'post_links', 'posts_answers', 'posts_moderator_nomination', 'posts_orphaned_tag_wiki', 'posts_privilege_wiki', 'posts_questions', 'posts_tag_wiki', 'posts_tag_wiki_excerpt', 'posts_wiki_placeholder', 'stackoverflow_posts', 'tags', 'users', 'votes']

Which is correct.

Why does the latter find the dataset but not the former?

Comment: A dry run can be used to estimate bytes processed/billed or syntax validity but you won't actually get the query results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a dryRun there is no jobIb in the response (as @Guillem mentions in his comment) thus the **None** in the error message

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectone/queries/None?maxResults=0&location=US: Not found: Job projectone:US.None

You can try [bigQuert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) playground to check the response on a clean environment.

This is an example of the response:

```
{
  "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
  "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "mydata-1470162410749",
    "location": "US"
  },
  "totalBytesProcessed": "30201595278",
  "jobComplete": true,
  "cacheHit": false
}
```

I used a simplified version of your SQL

`` SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions ``

Comment: That solved it thank you! Do you have any advice on how you would create a query that only works if the size of the data being looked at is below X. Trying to make sure my  google cloud bill isn't too expensive which is why I was trying to use dry run = True.

Comment: This is a very general and common question. You can start with this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs which can help you start and if you have a more specific question I suggest to open another question. Good Luck!!